# Can we estimate ATE (average treatment effect at the population level) using both marginal or conditional models?

Tags: marginal-effect, conditional

If I understood correctly, in principle when we estimate an unconditional/unadjusted treatment effect, it means marginal effect and vice-versa. If so, I wonder if the average treatment effect (ATE) at the population level is the marginal effect estimate only? Can we estimate also conditional ATE by conditioning on covariates. I searched a variety of resources, but still not sure about these. So, I really appreciate your clarity. I look forward to receiving your support.

Comment: Are you asking if you can recover the marginal estimate from conditional estimates?

Comment: Thanks Demetri Pananos. Yes, I'm asking that. Also, I wish to know when we estimate ATE (average treatment effect), is it always done from marginal effect model?

Comment: You can always estimate CTE (conditional treatment effects).  Estimation of population average treatment effects (PATE) is a daunting task because you'd have to have access to the full sample selection algorithm, e.g., the sample would have to be a simple random sample or a probability sample from the population and you'd need to know the sampling probabilities.  That comment applies in general, but in the special case where the response variable Y is continuous and you are using a linear model the SATE equals the PATE when there are no covariates interacting with treatment.

Comment: Thanks Frank Harrel for useful explanations.

Answer (score 1):

You can recover the ATE from conditional estimates.  Assume for now you have a randomized experiment so $Y^1, Y^0 \perp A$, where $A$ is some treatment. You also have data on a stratifying variable $L$. For example, $Y$ could be risk of death within 30 days of treatment, $A$ is drug (placebo or new treatment), and $L$ is age ($L=0$ is young, $L=1$ is old).

The ATE, is  $$ ATE = E[Y\mid A=1] - E[Y\mid A=0] \>.$$

Note also that from the law of iterated expectation

$$ E[Y \mid A] = E[Y \mid A, L=0]P(L=0) + E[Y \mid A, L=1]P(L=1) \>. $$

Hence, we can estimate causal contrasts simply by weighting the strata specific estimates.  Here is an example in R.  First, I'll generate some of the data

```
N <- 5000
L <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.3)
A <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.4 + 0.2*L)
Y <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.4 + 0.2*A - 0.1*L)
```

Note that  $Y^1, Y^0 \perp A\mid L$ so in this example a difference in marginal means doesn't even give us the ATE so we have to estimate the conditional quantities and weight them to estimate the ATE (which is 0.2 in this case).

```r
# First, estimate the weights

p_weights = prop.table(xtabs(~L))

#conditional estimates
smry <- aggregate(Y ~ A+L, FUN = mean)

# Estimates in treatment
conditional_E_y_1 = smry[(smry$A==1), ]$Y
E_y_1 = conditional_E_y_1 %*% p_weights

# Estimates in control
conditional_E_y_0 = smry[(smry$A==0), ]$Y
E_y_0 = conditional_E_y_0 %*% p_weights

ate = E_y_1 - E_y_0

ate
#>           [,1]
#> [1,] 0.2173959
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

That's pretty close.  If we replicate this calculation, generating new data from the same code each time, you can see it will center over the true ATE of 0.2 where as the marginal difference will be biased.

[image]

In general, we can do this using regression as well.  Computing a "marginal effect" is akin to weighting.  I'll let you look that up if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks Demetri Pananos. It's interesting and informative example with justifications. Just one more question is why weighting has been done on L (age) instead of treatment (A)? In propensity score (PS) methods for PS matching, inverse-probability of treatment weight, stratification and covariate adjustment, I have learnt that the default choice for weighting is done on treatment to serve both ATE and ATT/ATET (average treatment effect on the treated).

Comment: The weighting is done by $L$ for two reasons.  First, potential outcomes are independent of treatment conditional on $L$, so we must calculate the ATE within each strata (i.e. the CATE, C standing for "Conditional").  Next, we want to know the ATE in the population, so we weight the CATE by the estimated proportion of patients within the strata in the population. 

You could use inverse probability weighting/propensity score matching, but your question was about recovering marginal effects from conditional effects.

Comment: Thanks Demetri Pananos. Very interesting. It's a bit straightforward given just one covariate (L). How about the process of calculating weight and estimating ATE if we have two covariates onwards, especially some of which are continuous? Sorry to ask you further questions, yet it gives more insight.

Comment: @user332276. You probably want to look at something called "marginal effects" in those cases. You can do this with regression more generally.

Comment: Thanks Demetri so much. I would really appreciate if you could give me just a coding example of regression for marginal effects that I could loop up if possible

Comment: @user332276 you’re free to look at   The documentation for the “marginaleffects” library in R

Comment: I don't understand how in practice you'd know the population weights.

Comment: @FrankHarrell. You wouldn't.  If the same was a SRS or weights were estimated via a survey or something (just as an example) maybe that would work, but this is simply meant to demonstrate how the ATE can be recovered from conditional estimates.

Comment: @user332276 I explain in detail how to estimate average marginal effects after matching in the `MatchIt` [vignette](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/estimating-effects.html) and after weighting in the `WeightIt` [vignette](https://ngreifer.github.io/WeightIt/articles/estimating-effects.html). Both vignettes rely on the `marginaleffects` package.

Comment: @DemetriPananos I'm still not clear how you can do what you suggest without knowing sampling probabilities.

Comment: @FrankHarrell So far as I am concerned, that is not within the scope of the question.  Granted, that is something that would need to be answered to use this in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine a randomized experiment for the effect of treatment $A$ on outcome $Y$ with measured covariate $X$. (You can also imagine a sample that has already been matched or weighted so that it resembles a randomized experiment based on the adjusted-for covariates; everything I say here applies.) We'll define the conditional ATE (CATE) at $X=x$ as
$$
E[Y|A=1,X=x] - E[Y|A=0,X=x]
$$
and the marginal ATE (ATE) as
$$
E_X[E[Y|A=1,X]] - E_X[E[Y|A=0,X]]
$$

If you fit the linear model
$$
E[Y|A,X] = \beta_0 + \tau A + \beta_1 X
$$
then $\hat\tau$ is an estimate of the CATEs, which are assumed to be equal no matter what value $X$ takes. It also happens to be equal to the estimate of the ATE. If the true CATEs differ across $X$, then your estimates of the CATE will be biased. However, your estimate of the ATE will be unbiased.

If you instead fit the linear model
$$
E[Y|A,X] = \beta_0 + \tau A + \beta_1 X + \beta_2 AX
$$
then the estimated CATEs are allowed to vary as $\text{CATE}(x) = \hat\tau + \hat\beta_2x$ and the ATE is the average of the CATEs across the sample, which is equal to $\hat\tau + \hat\beta_2\bar X$. In this case, it is possible to estimate CATEs and the ATE when adjusting for covariates. If the true model is linear and the CATEs vary across $X$, then your estimates of the CATEs and ATE will be unbiased.

What if the true data-generating is not linear, but instead has a curvilinear shape that is not captured by your linear model, and the true CATEs differ across $X$? We already know that your estimate of the CATEs will be biased if you fit the first model when the true CATEs vary across $X$. If we fit the second model, the estimates of the CATEs will still be biased. *You have to get the form of the model right to validly estimate CATEs*. However, no matter what form the true outcome model takes, the estimates of the ATE will be unbiased regardless of which model you use; the model exists solely to increase the precision of the estimate.

This is the reason many causal inference-focused statisticians prefer to estimate the ATE over CATEs. Given the conservative assumptions that CATEs vary across levels of covariates and that the relationship between the covariates and outcome is nonlinear, many believe it is impossible to validly estimate CATEs without making extreme modeling assumptions, and one's estimates of the CATEs will vary largely based on the modeling choices you make. However, none of that is so with ATEs. In a randomized experiment (or a sample that has been adequately matched or weighted in such a way that the simple difference in outcome means is unbiased for the causal effect), no matter what assumptions you make on true outcome model, your estimate of the ATE will be unbiased.

Frank Harrell's criticism of this outlook as described in the comments to OP is that the ATE is always estimated with reference to some population, but in the absence of a probability sample, that population is ambiguous or nonexistent, in which case it doesn't matter that your ATE is unbiased for the population in which it is estimated. In contrast, if you somehow get the true outcome model correct and can estimate the CATEs, they will be valid no matter what the source of the sample is or whether it is representative. In addition, CATEs provide more useful information about the prognosis for individual patients, which is more useful in medical decision making. My impression is that researchers who prefer the ATE would argue that the assumption that the study population is representative of some meaningful population is more tenable than the assumption that the outcome model is correctly specified, which is necessary for valid interpretation of the CATEs.

Comment: Thank you so much Demetri Pananos for a thoughtful illustration on the point. Perhaps, please accept if I ask two more questions. In the above example, as we set a randomized experiment, I assume that confounders balance across treatments, so why do we still adjust for covariate X? Also, how can we explain whatever assumptions we make on true outcome model, the estimate of the ATE will be unbiased? since I guess we still work out the right form of model to serve an unbiased estimate?

Comment: I'm not Demetri :) You adjust for covariates in the outcome model to increase the precision (reduce the standard error) of the treatment effect estimate. This is always a good idea in experiments (or after balancing) because you increase precision at no cost. [Negi and Wooldridge (2020)](https://doi.org/10.1080/07474938.2020.1824732) explain why misspecification of the model doesn't affect bias of the ATE. The treatment is independent of all variables in the model, so it doesn't matter what is in the model or what form that model takes.

Comment: Thanks Noah so much (I'm sorry for mis-appreciating your name). Anyway, given your explanations, it's clear for now. Thank you again.